# trying to erase a DVD+RW in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: dvd

I burned a video onto a DVD+RW Windows Vista several years ago. I now want to erase the DVD using Ubuntu 11.10 and install Ubuntu 12.4 Studio onto this disc. I tried to blank the disc, but it didn't work. And now I can't get Windows 7 to read it as well as Ubuntu 11.10. How do I erase this disc for reuse?

Comment: Yes, sorry I mistyped the question. The DVD is a rewritable DVD+RW disc. You're supposed to be able to rewrite it many times. I've done this many times in Windows. And no, I'm not a fan of Windows. I'm transitioning to using Linux as my main OS. Hope this clears this up.

Comment: Please edit the original question, rather than indicating corrections in comments.

Comment: How does one edit their question? I'm new to using the Ask Ubuntu forums, but have often searched them and found many useful solutions and answers. Also, I see that the term DVD+RW is in my question remarks. I thought that RW meant rewritable.

Comment: Sorry. Just saw the edit link. But I'm not sure why my question needs editing.

Comment: I have edited and corrected the typo. You had typed DVD+R, while you intended to type DVD+RW. So now you don't need to edit it any more. :) In any case, your question may be deemed off topic as Ubuntu 11.10 has reached its end of life and is not supported anymore. It is quite possible the DVD+RW is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the disc is specifically meant to be reused, burned data on DVDs tends to be more or less permanent. It's possible to burn new files onto it, but you'd really be better off just buying a new DVD for the task. You probably won't be able to effectively use that one as an Ubuntu LiveCD.

Answer (score -1):

I use "brasero".  On the "Tools" menu, select "Blank ...".  A "Disc Blanking" dialog box will open.  Click on "Blank".

On some drives, you can use

```
sudo cdrecord dev=/dev/cdrom blank=fast
```

That does not work for my drive.